# How to inline two elements?

Tags: html, css

Actually I wanted to make a container (`project-item`) resembling the below image
[image]

I want to align the project logo and the title (h3) together in one line however I am not able to find out a suitable solution

I ended up making something of this kind
[image: what i made]

```css
/* Updated Project Section Styles */
.project-section {
  border-radius: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-project {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1%;
  margin: 2%;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
}

.grid-project .project-item {
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: .5s ease;
  padding: 5%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Updated to display items in a column */
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.grid-project .project-item:hover {
  background: #6b6b6b3f;
}

.grid-project .project-item .project-tag {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.grid-project .project-item .project-tag span {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.grid-project a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.grid-project .project-item h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px; /* Adjusted margin for spacing */
}

.grid-project .project-item p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.grid-project .project-item .project-logo {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-project">
  <a href="https://dsc.gg/accumen" target="_blank">
    <div class="project-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" class="project-logo">
        <h3>Accumen</h3>
        <h4 class="project-info">
          <a href="https://github.com/infinotiver/accumen">View Github Repository </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="project-tag">
            <span>Python</span>
            <span>Discord Bot</span>
            <span>Education based</span>
            <span> AI </span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I tried `display:flex` but that just inlines every element of project (descriptions and tags) but I didn't want that to happen

---

[image: Working Image]

Comment: Can you pls provide your HTML code as well

Comment: Added my html code

Comment: Perfect just made a snippet and added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 2 containers that wrap your image and the rest of your element respectively. Then with their parent element display: flex and flex-direction: row. (Also added a gap). I also removed the a tag that was wrapping many block element as it can lead to unexpected behavior and is not semanticaly  correct.Pls see snippet in full page and note that you will need to make some adjustment for small screens.

```css
/* Updated Project Section Styles */

 .project-item {
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: .5s ease;
  padding: 5%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* Updated to display items in a row */
  gap: 20px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.project-item:hover {
  background: #6b6b6b3f;
}

.project-item .project-tag {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.project-item .project-tag span {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.grid-project .project-item h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px; /* Adjusted margin for spacing */
}

.grid-project .project-item p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.grid-project .project-item .project-logo {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="https://dsc.gg/accumen" target="_blank">Click me</a>
    <div class="project-item">
      <div class="left-side">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" class="project-logo">
      </div>
      <div class="right-side">
        <h3>Accumen</h3>
        <h4 class="project-info">
          <a href="https://github.com/infinotiver/accumen">View Github Repository </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="project-tag">
            <span>Python</span>
            <span>Discord Bot</span>
            <span>Education based</span>
            <span> AI </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Just wanted to know how do I remove the gap before the tags and the project descriptions?  ( I am editing my question to show you the example pic)

Comment: So if I properly understand  you want to horizontaly alignement thé top of image tag with top of Acumen right?

Comment: Actually, the project tags and description is a little indented towards right , i just want to remove the extra indent

Comment: You Can decrease thé gap value in .project-item

Comment: That doesn't works. `gap` just reduces gap between the elements but that indent is not reduced

Comment: So you mean Python is a little indented on the right compared to Accumen

Comment: I mean that "Python" and other description is indented towards right as compared to the image (logo) . I want the `project-tags` and description (`p`) to begin directly below the image ( like no further indent ). I will edit that pic to show you what I mean if I am not able to explain it nicely (sorry) @Mehdi

Comment: For that according to your change you will need either to use css grid or remove project-tag div from right-side div and put it out of project-item div in wrapper div. Then wrapper div display flex and flex-direction column and also project-item div display flex and flex-direction :row